# Android webview auto fill iFrame values

Tags: javascript, android

thanks in advance.
I want to know, how i can access an iFrame from a loaded page in webview and set some values inside that iframe form.

I tried with parent.getElementById(?) but it doesn't help me...

```
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://nesach.justice.gov.il/mashkonot/forms/fMashIyunMishkunContent.aspx");
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            int user=5466687,user2=1122;
            view.loadUrl("javascript:var f = window.frames['frmAddBakasha'];alert('Hello');");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Frame element loaded');");

            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('MisparBakashot').value = '"+user+"';");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('frmAddBakasha');");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;");                
            view.loadUrl("javascript:doc.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';");                                         

        }
    });
```

Comment: off topic because: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Rene now check it....

Answer (score 1):

Due to security restrictions, unless the `iframe` belongs to the same domain, you won't be able to access `iframe`s child elements.

See, for example, [`elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint#Notes):

> If the element at the specified point belongs to another document (for example, an iframe's subdocument), the element in the DOM of the document the method is called on (in the iframe case, the iframe itself) is returned.

I believe, same applies to `getElementById`.